# Error: POM not present while using mvn deploy command

Tags: maven, pom.xml, artifactory

I am using below mentioned command to send jar from my local workspace to Artifcatory in maven repo. I am not using pom.xml to do so. I have configured setting.xml with credentials for Artifactory.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=https://myartifactory.fkc.com/maven-prereleases
-DrepositoryId= arti-mavenpre -Dfile=trial.zip -DgroupId=com/org/mydir
-DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=zip
```

I get following error while executing above command:

```
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no
POM in this directory (C:\Users\raji\script). Please verify you invoked Maven
from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to use pom.xml file. How to make it work without pom?

Thank you.

Comment: The [`deploy:deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) goal does not require a project, so it's unclear how you might have gotten that error. The command you ran was not the one you thought you ran, or the deploy plugin you're using isn't the official plugin. Clean your local repo `~/.m2/repository` and run again `mvn deploy:deploy-file ...`.

Comment: Hi Tunaki. Where can I find the plugins installed? I could see few at "C:\Users\raji\.m2\repository"

Comment: I used following link to download maven in windows machine (2012 R2 server):
http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

I downloaded apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip for install.

Comment: As I commented before, clean your local repo at `C:\Users\raji\.m2\repository`, and do the command `mvn deploy:deploy-file` again, there is no reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: I cleaned it and executed the command again. It now failed with the error that it could not contact maven central to download deploy plugin. I thought it could be some proxy issue. And then set proxy, still did not work. So I manually placed the plugin but still it searches it in maven central (maven.repo) and fails with error that plugin is not found. Plugin is placed in following location:

C:\Users\raji\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-deploy-plugin\2.8.2

There is a jar and a pom file in it. I copied it from a server where it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was the error. I am using powershell to execute maven command and it requires double quotes for execution. After using double quotes, its working fine.

C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn -s "C:\Users\my-user.m2\settings.xml" -Dversion="$(Build.BuildNumber)" -Durl="https://my-artifactory.ayz.com/maven-prereleases" -DgroupId="com.mycomp.mydir" -Dfile="C:\agent_work\1\a_PublishedWebsites\test_$(Build.BuildNumber).zip" -Dpackaging="zip" -DrepositoryId="my-artifac
tory" -DgeneratePom=true -DartifactId="test" -B deploy:deploy-file

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your script is the empty space `-DrepositoryId= arti-mavenpre` between the repositoryId and the value. I had a similar problem and that fixed it.